# How to not reload image with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Just a quick implementation question. If I subscribe to a list with AngularFire2 like in the example:

```
this.items = this.af.database.list('/items');
```

And say those items have a image source attached to them:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
        <img [src]="item.src" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Whenever the items change, even if the item has the same image source, the images flash and reload. Is there a way to only update the properties of the item that actually changed? In Angular 1 you could use `track by` but in Angular 2 I'm not sure how to implement it with the `async` pipe and the `FirebaseListObservable`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `trackBy`, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async; trackBy: someUniqueProperty">
        <img [src]="item.src" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where `someUniqueProperty` is a property of `item`.